# How to find efficiently all positive linear dependencies between some vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, memory, inequalities

I've got these vectors

```
vecs=
{{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0},    {1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,1,-1},  {1,0,-1,1,0,-1,1,0,-1},
 {1,0,-1,1,0,0,-1,0,1},   {1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,-1},   {1,0,0,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1},
 {1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0},    {-1,0,1,0,0,-1,1,0,-1},  {-1,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,1},
 {-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,0,0,-1}, {-1,1,-1,1,0,-1,1,-1,1}, {-1,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,1}, 
 {-1,1,0,-1,1,-1,0,1,0},  {0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1},   {0,-1,0,1,-1,1,0,-1,1},
 {0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0},   {0,-1,1,-1,0,1,-1,1,0},  {0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0}}
```

And I would like to find all linear dependencies with positive coefficients between them. I started with

```
ns = NullSpace[Transpose[vecs]]
```

which gave me

```
{{2,2,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3},  {2,-1,2,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0}, 
 {2,-1,-1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0},  {1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,3,0,0,0}, 
 {2,-1,-1,0,-1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0}, {-1,2,2,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
 {-1,2,-1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  {-1,2,-1,0,-1,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
 {-1,-1,2,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  {-1,-1,-1,3,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}
```

so there is one linear dependence with nonnegative coefficients (the fourth one). To check whether there are others, I made a system of inequalities with

```
ineqs = Simplify[Union[Map[# >= 0 &, Table[x[k], {k, Length[ns]}].ns]]]
```

which returns

```
{x[1]>=0,x[2]>=0,x[3]>=0,x[4]>=0,x[5]>=0,x[6]>=0,x[7]>=0,x[8]>=0,x[9]>=0,x[10]>=0,
 2 x[1]+2 x[2]+2 x[3]+x[4]+2 x[5] >= x[6]+x[7]+x[8]+x[9]+x[10],
 2 x[1]+x[4]+2 (x[6]+x[7]+x[8])   >= x[2]+x[3]+x[5]+x[9]+x[10],
 2 x[2]+x[4]+2 (x[6]+x[9])        >= x[1]+x[3]+x[5]+x[7]+x[8]+x[10],
 2 x[3]+x[4]+2 (x[7]+x[9]+x[10])  >= x[1]+x[2]+x[5]+x[6]+x[8]}
```

but my notebook runs out of memory on both `Solve[ineqs]` and `Reduce[ineqs]`.

What is the proper way?

Comment: Try: AllTrue[#, NonNegative] & /@ ns

Comment: @DanielHuber Output is `{False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False}`

Comment: Yes, this means the forth vector has all positive entries.

Comment: @DanielHuber Sorry maybe the question is not formulated clearly enough. I need to find all subsets of `vecs` that have linear dependencies with positive entries. It is true that all such dependencies are obtained from some linear combinations of those from `ns`, but how to find these combinations efficiently I don't know.

Comment: "Pick[ns, AllTrue[#, NonNegative] & /@ ns]" gives you the coefficients of the linear combinations and "Pick[ns, AllTrue[#, NonNegative] & /@ ns].vecs" shows you that the linear combination is zero.

Comment: @DanielHuber This only says that the subset of `vecs` consisting of the vectors numbered 1,2,3,5,13 and 15 does have linear dependence with positive coefficients. There might be other subsets with this property, no? I need to find all of them.

Comment: No, "AllTrue[#, NonNegative] & /@ ns" picks out only those with non negative coefficients. A further remark: theoretically you should also look for "non-positive" but presumably Nullspace does not return such combinations.

Comment: @DanielHuber I mean that the fourth entry of `ns` has all numbers nonnegative, so choosing only nonzero ones (first, second, third, fifth, thirteenth and fifteenth) one gets a positive dependence between the corresponding vectors from `vecs`. Now suppose that some linear combination of entries from `ns` also has all numbers nonnegative; then choosing those which are nonzero one finds another subset of `vecs` with positive linear dependence. So the task is to find all linear combinations of entries from `ns` with all entries nonnegative.

Comment: You can achieve this by: "AllTrue[#, NonPositive] & /@ n" but I do not think that this is necessary, because NullSpace will return combinations where the number of positive coef. is equal or grater than the negative ones. However, I do not have a proof for this.

Comment: @DanielHuber For example (I found it using `FindInstance`): `2vecs[[1]]+vecs[[16]]+vecs[[17]]+vecs[[18]]` is the zero vector. This dependence cannot be obtained from any of those in `ns` without taking linear combinations. With linear combinations, it is `ns[[1]]+ns[[2]]+ns[[3]]`, which is `{6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3}`

Comment: You are right, I will think about it.

Comment: Here is an idea: Find a solution using FindInstance. Then  from every base vector subtract the component in direction of the solution, ensuring that this solution is no more spanned by the base. Then repeat until no more solution is found.

Comment: I think any full solution to this problem will require integer linear programming. And it might need to be done "by hand" to force use of approximate methods for the LP parts (`Reduce` is using exact LP under the hood).